# Need to change text information related to video

Tags: javascript, jquery

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/99737964/video%20online/sermonvideos.html

I am new to jquery, javascript and coding in general.  I have made a media player that i can click on and have different videos appear in a box, but now i am wondering how i can also make text appear to the right of the video box which will display video title and information.  I have text appear now, but i do not understand how to get the previous text to disappear after clicking on the new video.  check the url to see.  thanks for help!

get source code from site.

Comment: like the same way u make appear the video

Comment: and basically u need a jquery tab menu search for it on web and u will get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `.html()` or `.text()` functions of jquery and give `id` or `class` to an element that will contain the title and information of the clicked video like:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() { 
       $('.videos').click(function() { 
           var value = $(this).attr('title');
           $('#myInfo').html(value); //this should do the trick or 


           $('#myInfo').text(value); //this should do the trick
       })
   });
</script>
```

and the html

```
<div class = "videos" title = "this is an information">video 1</div>
<div class = "videos" title = "this is an information">video 2</div>
<div class = "videos" title = "this is an information">video 3</div>
<div class = "videos" title = "this is an information">video 4</div>
<div class = "videos" title = "this is an information">video 5</div>

<div id = "myInfo"></div>
```